# 90% sudden drop in search engine ranking with no changes made

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines, ranking, google-ranking

This is a recurring topic, but I am very very panicking right now...

I noticed a 90% "impressions" drop (from 60k to 5k) from **2013-03-05** to **2013-03-06**.
My keywords dropped, and for a few of them I don't even appear in the first 25 search results pages that I checked.

This happened in just 24 hours, **without** me making absolutely **any** change on the website.

I'm really panicking now, I never did any black-hat SEO, I always followed Google "rules", and see where it leads me :( I believe I'm providing a good quality website, at least my members thank me for it, this means it should be good enough. I'm doing everything I can to provide quality. I really don't know what else to do apart from paying someone thousands of euros to help me with SEO.

Does someone have any idea about that scary drop?

I would love to follow each and every possible lead one could give me.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please share your URL.

Comment: I hope it is not against the forum rules : www.escorts-eden.com

Comment: my ranking dropped off the planet, figured out my stuff was scraped and put all over the place, went through the whole dmca notice deal with Google and they took the splogs down, today I'm back on first page, maybe check for duplicate content?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure it is that. I know that backpage.com steals profiles (without even the consent of my members), but content is not duplicated as the layout is different and it stills lacks info. Plus, my 90% drop happened at the same time that everyone that complains on the Internet recently :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google releases many new algorithms each month and any of them may de-rank any number of sites.  Unfortunately, your situation is a pretty common occurrence.

I would suggest following this disscussion on WebmasterWorld.com: [Google Updates and SERP Changes - March 2013](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4550136-2-30.htm).  From that forum thread, it is pretty clear that something happened on March 6th.    The first person to report something is user Wilburforce:

> Between yesterday morning and today my Home page has dropped back from page 5 to page 47 for key term.

But pretty soon other people are reporting problems too.

> **epmaniac**: my main site has suddenly vanished
>
> **foxhunter**: Any news on an algorithm change in the last 24 hours? Yesterday was the highest traffic day I have ever had, and today all but a few pages are nowhere to be found in the serps.
>
> **joe121**: Yeah, I'm seeing HUGE changes today.

There are lots of theories as to what this algorithm update from Google is:

- Panda update
- Something to do with Europe
- Penalization of a new link network

It is clearly a change that is effecting a lot of websites and nobody knows what is behind it yet.

Here is a forum that has put together a survey of sites hit by this update to try to figure out what is causing it: http://www.warriorforum.com/adsense-ppc-seo-discussion-forum/763655-take-survey-march-6th-google-update-lets-find-out-what-caused.html

Comment: Thank you for this great answer Stephen.
I'm new to SEO, and I know this is a pretty specific job in itself. But I did everything "by the book" (I think one can say that, "by the book" ?), and I don't understand why I'm hit and my competitors are absolutely NOT, they are still in first page.

Comment: Google is free to rewrite the book at any time.  Their algorithms also make mistakes all the time.  Sites get caught up because they are in some way similar to sites that Google doesn't like despite the fact that they may be a pretty great site.

Comment: Is there any way (aside from paying someone thousands of euros) not to be harmed? I'm of good faith, I work hard, I do only White Hat, I searched myself many suggestions made by Google to improve SEO, and for now it worked, but since the last week, I'm nearly not existing at all in Google :'( I don't mean to whine, but still I'm really panicking right now...

Comment: I've never even heard that paying thousands can keep a site from being harmed.  On the contrary, many sites get harmed despite spending multiples of that with Adwords.

Comment: I meant paying someone who is a professional in SEO and who could help me avoid beginner's naive mistakes, and optimize my on/off site SEO, for example. Adwords forbids my activity in any case :)

Comment: Even having a professional giving you good advice is no foolproof strategy.  Many SEO experts were hit by iterations of the Penguin and Panda Google updates over the last couple years.  Yes, problems can be caused by simple mistakes that are easy to avoid if you have somebody who knows what they are doing.  However, anybody who guarantees rankings is selling snake oil.

Comment: I did not know that expression (selling snake oil) because I'm French, but I'll remember it, thx :)
Yes, I know there are many bad-purpose thieves that pretend to be SEO experts, but it's a matter of judging if I can do better alone that with someone's help.
Anyway, I'm asking myself why : 1) a competitor of mine is still showing in first page in Google, whereas it's website has been definitely closed a few days ago... And 2) why another competitor shows up to 30 consecutive links in SERP, hiding anyone behind him... It should not happen...

Comment: I added another link to a survey to my answer.

Comment: Forgive my noob question, but what is SAPE link ? I have a few (half a dozen) banner exchange on my homepage, but that's it, nothing more... :'(

Comment: First I've heard of it as well.  It appears to be a specific link network.  You can Google it.

Comment: Yes I did it. It seems black hat to me, and I never did such a thing.